# Logging Current Directory/Filename in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was wondering if there is a way to log the current filename or directory in React Native. Similar to how NodeJS does it with `__filename` and `__dirname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible since all the source code gets bundled together into one big file, and then a source map is provided so that you can debug it in the original structure.
You can see that by calling this code snippet somewhere in your code:

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

In a regular javascript you would get the entire trace with files and line numbers, but in react-native you get somthing like:

```
Error
at Login (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:83009:9)
at instantiate (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:5712:18)
at new Login (eval at proxyClass (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:5730:16), <anonymous>:4:17)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:22051:19)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:22033:13)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:21952:15)
at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:20425:29)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:22134:28)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:22015:13)
at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:20425:29)"
```

which shows you the real files are gone.

Comment: If I run react-native with remote debug via chrome. I do get file and line numbers on the far right of each console.log. Is there a way I can access that information within my code? Even if it is only while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following babel's plugins for that purporses into your package:

```bash
$ npm i babel-plugin-transform-line
$ npm i babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename
```

Where:

- [babel-plugin-transform-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-line) rewrites `__line` into the current source line number static value.
- [babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename) rewrites `__filename` and `__dirname` into the current source filename and the directory.

Then add the plugins into your `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-dirname-filename', 'babel-plugin-transform-line']
};
```

Now you can use the variables in your code:

```js
console.log(__filename, __dirname, __line);

// Prints: /Users/user/TestApp/App.js /Users/user/TestApp 62
```